# Section as main section

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Is that semanticlly correct to use `section` element as main content section of a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadly, no.

[HTML5Doctor says](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/):

> What we’ve been doing wrong is using section to wrap content in order to style it, or **to demarcate the main content area** from the nav, header, footer etc. These are jobs for div, not section.

Since that article was written, the `<main>` element has been invented, for your exact use case.

Comment: [I'd say](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14894715/1591669): broadly, yes. Otherwise you couldn't have a separate `header`/`footer` that belongs just to the main content versus the whole page.

Answer (score 4):

You could, but I would encourage you to use the new `main` element instead!

e.g.

```
<main role="main">

</main>
```

See [the main element](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2013/01/html5/the-main-element) and [further examples on using the main element](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2013/02/html5/further-examples-on-using-the-main-element).

Answer (score 0):

You could say that you implictly use `section` as soon as you have a heading (`h1`-`h6`) that is not the heading of a sectioning element.

So these two documents are semantically equivalent:

1)

```
<body>
  <h1>John's cool site</h1>
  <nav>…</nav>
  <h2>A nice article</h2> <!--- main content starts with this heading -->
  <p>I like bees.</p>
</body> <!-- main content ends at the end of the document -->
```

2)

```
<body>
  <h1>John's cool site</h1>
  <nav>…</nav>
  <section><!--- main content starts with this opening tag -->
    <h2>A nice article</h2> <!-- now you could use h1 here, too --> 
    <p>I like bees.</p>
  </section><!-- main content ends with this closing tag -->
</body>
```

So, yes, you can use `section` for the main content (in many cases `article` would be more suitable, though). You can use `section` for *every* heading-content group (unless `article`, `nav` or `aside` should be used, of course).

As soon as you use sectioning elements for all these heading-content groups, you could use `h1` everywhere.

There are even some edge cases where you'd be required to explictly use a sectioning element for the main content. Namely, if your page contains content that is not part of the main content and that is not suitable for `header`, `footer` or `address` (nor `aside`/`nav`). If you wouldn't use `section` (or `article`) in such a case, this content would still belong to the main content.

A more (I'd even say, very) common example where you should use `section`/`article` for the main content would be a page where you need a separate `header`/`footer` for the main content, e.g. blog post page: The whole page might have a `footer` (which contains info about the whole blog). Now, if we wouldn't use a sectioning element for the main content (→ the blog post), we couldn't have a separate `footer` (with author info, tags, categories etc.) just for that article.

```
<body>
  <h1>John's blog</h1>
  <article>
    <h1>My first blog post</h1>
    <p>…</p>
    <footer> <!-- applies to the blog post only (article) -->
      Tags: introduction, aboutme
    </footer> 
  </article>
  <footer> <!-- applies to the whole page (body) -->
    Blog of John Doe — 2013
    <p><small>All content licensed under Creative Commons</small></p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

So I'd advise: if in doubt, explictly use `section`/`article` for the main content of a page.